# Entity Property in URL and SEO

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, seo

I have coded my ASP.NET MVC application in a way that allows stored entities to be retrieved via a friendly name in the URL, for example:

> www.mysite.com/artists/james-brown/songs

Where `james-brown` is a URL friendly string stored on my `Artist` entity.

Now imagine I add an artist that no one has heard of before, and no one ever navigated to that artist's songs page.

How would Google/Yahoo/Other Search Engines know that my site does indeed have songs for that unknown artist.

Do I create a sitemap and maintain it through code as I add / remove artists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few defined known ways to make the new links visible to search engine world.

**XML and HTML Sitemap:**

Add it to sitemap and submit it through webmaster tools.
HTML sitemaps are another way to achieve it. If your site has footer sitemap, you can add it to them.

**Internal Links**

Create internal links from your high ranking pages or highly crawled pages to the new pages. Google and other search engines tend to crawl pages where the content changes frequently. So if you have a refreshed content pages, try adding it to those pages and chances are high for those pages to be discovered quickly.

**External Links**

Create links from external blogs, company blogs and sites like pagetube.org which can help it to be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just add them to either sitemap, internal or even external links